# unable to click ActiveX control and form control Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook,which contains ActiveX control button and form control button and macros are assigned to those controls. these controls are working fine in excel 2007 but when I open this workbook in excel 2010, I am unable to click on those controls. Whenever I click on any button,it goes in design mode. Is there any solution available??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neha your Excel Setting are preventing the ActiveX Buttons to become Active. Do this

Click On the `File Tab` | `Options`. Click on the `Trust Center` in the dialog box that opens and then click on `Trust Center Setting`. Go to `ActiveX Setting` and click on the option button `Prompt Me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions`

Close the file and re-open it. You will get a `Yellow Popup Bar` asking you to enable the ActiveX. Click on yes and you are done :)