# Made a workbook in 2010, now the radio buttons don't work when opened in 2013

Tags: radio-button, excel-2010, compatibility, excel-2013

Just as the title says - the radio buttons cannot be selected, and the user also can't right click on them. I struggled to find someone else who had the same problem, but we followed the steps in these two posts and it did not fix it:

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b8f0af82-0bb8-4799-aa62-1dbcbc5b7742/excel-2010-macros-does-not-work-after-updates-9dec2014?forum=excel)

&

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529269/unable-to-click-activex-control-and-form-control-excel-2010)

If it's any help, when the cursor is hovering over any other part of the document, it is the thick plus sign, but when it is hovered over the buttons, it still turns into a regular pointer cursor the same way it would if they were working.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out. My user didn't enable content, haha. -_-